# Sql custom statement

Tags: sql

What is the Programme for Sql data in Microsoft Expression Web Custom Statement similar to following Access database statement:

```
Sum(IIf([accident]![Rly]='CR',1,0))
```

Comment: Welcome to stack!  Please take a moment to familiarize yourself with our methods via the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).  Taken out of context your question is very precise which is wonderful; but its difficult to answer the question since we need a little context.  For example I know this is a different SQL way to do it I don't know if it applies to expression web.  `CASE WHEN accident.RLY='CR' then 1 else 0 end`?  So if this is part of a query; seeing the whole query woudl help garner context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure you will be able to use this format as this will run against each individual row and always return 1 or 0. To run against your whole query to get the total sum you need something similar to this:

```
SELECT SUM(Rly) FROM
(SELECT ID, CASE WHEN Accident.Rly = 'CR' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END Rly
FROM Accident)
```

The syntax may be slightly different but hopefully this will set you in the right direction.

Comment: If this would work then you don't need the sub-select; `select sum(case HEN Accident.Rly = 'CR' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) from accident` would do it

Comment: Sir, the following statement in Expression Web is work for one criteria "SELECT COUNT(Rly) AS CR FROM SPAD WHERE Rly='CR'". Now the issue is that if more than one criteria is required in same column, for example Count(Rly) AS ER FROM SPAD WHERE Rly='ER', what statement will be required. Please help.

Comment: Are you looking for the total count of 'CR' & 'ER' together, or are you looking to specify the count of both seperately?

Comment: Try this: "SELECT S.Rly, Count(S.Rly) FROM SPAD S WHERE S.Rly IN ('CR', 'ER') GROUP BY S.Rly" This should give you a seperate count of each and you could add more by simply adding them to the IN section